# What do I do to highlight a text?

Tags: feature-request, formatting

I want to write a summarised form of a Wikipedia article, such as [**Stack Overflow Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow), in my answer.

Now if I quote something from the article it will be done like this-

> Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network, created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky.

Let this be a summarised form of whole like this - "***Stack Overflow is a platform where question and answer on various topics are shared by experts and internet users.***"

If I use a blockquote, some people refute the use of "**blockquotes '>'**" saying that it is not a quote, it is a summary.

Sometimes we need to quote a huge 4 page article in a ***summarised*** form, but then they say "**you cannot use quotes as it is a summary**" . So is there anything to highlight some important text (as in this case a summary) in a box like blockquotes or codeblocks.

And if not, it should be made in a suitable color (like blockquotes are yellow usually, and codes are grey) , maybe sky blue color or light red color or light green.

---

**NOTE:** ***The Wikipedia article is just an example. In my real case, I often have to post an answer by translating a very large 4-5 chapter stories, so I just quote it in summarised form. This is why the question asks if there is there any highlighting feature, or using blockquotes is fine.***

Comment: @HansPassant Why not quoting relevant parts from the source, and of course adding your words? I think it's sometimes good to quote the most relevant parts, just in case the link breaks someday.

Comment: @Maroun wikipedia article is only for example. Actually I had to quote a 4 page story in a different language, by translating it in english. Now I cannot translate a 4 page story in english and then quote it, so I wrote a summarised form and quoted it. But some users say that it cannot be done as it is a summarised form, which is absurd as a 4 page huge story is not good to be quoted completely, when we can summarise it a bit. This is why I'm asking

Comment: @JoshCaswell I had quoted the "part thay is not a quotation" only as an example to show . This is why I wrote "If I use **these** blockquotes". Anyways, is there any solution to it. What do we do to highlight a part of text, or should we just extend the usage of blockquotes to include highlighting also

Answer (score 5):

I'd approach this similarly to how you would write a paper: rephrase (no quotation block), inline quotation for smaller sentences ("quotation marks"), block quote for larger sections ("block quote", in papers often indented), and give references in all these cases. I don't think you need anything else, just to mark a "summary" Additional formats would just complicate things unnecessarily.

In your case I'd use any of the following forms. Use the following rule: do I use content of another source -> provide a reference, do I use the same format (literally copy-pasting) of another source -> use quotation marks (small portion) or block quotes (a lot). In your case (summary) you are using content of another source, but not the same format. Simply provide the source, and give an indication that you summarised (part of) the source.

The leading paragraph of the respective [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow), summarises the website as follows:

> Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the
>   Stack Exchange Network, created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel
>   Spolsky. It was created to be a more open alternative to earlier
>   question and answer sites such as Experts-Exchange. The name for the
>   website was chosen by voting in April 2008 by readers of Coding
>   Horror, Atwood's popular programming blog.

*or*

Stack Overflow is a questions-and-answers website that is part of the larger Stack Exchange Network ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow)). To provide an alternative to similar Q&A websites, Jeff Atwoord and Joel Spolsky launched it in 2008.

*or*

The name of Stack Overflow is not randomly chosen at all. In fact, it "was chosen by voting in April 2008 by readers of Coding Horror, Atwood's popular programming blog" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow)).